# How to import Apache Commons Net using Maven

Tags: java, apache, scala, maven, ftp

When I run `import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.{FTP, FTPClient}` I receive the error: `object apache is not a member of package org`. I am using Maven, and I tried adding

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons.net</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and/or

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

as well as various other similar packages to my pom.xml file, but nothing is working. This seems to be a very simple error yet I cannot figure out what I'm missing. This is my first time using Maven, am I misunderstanding how dependencies work? I am using Scala 2.11.6 if that matters.

Update: I was finally able to run the file I wanted through this command:

`mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.havas.plugins.test"`

Comment: can you tell me what is your scala class directory?? is it in `src/main/scala`? `import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.{FTP, FTPClient}` is the right import, seems your dependencies are not added.

Comment: Yes, the specific file is located at src/main/scala/com/havas.plugins/test.scala. Do I need to do something to add my dependencies other than just add the text to my pom.xml?

Comment: is the error on IDE or scala REPL?? if its IDE, try to synchronise `pom.xml`. Or the best approach is go to root of your project in terminal and fire `mvn clean compile` which makes sure that your maven dependencies are downloaded.

Comment: first of all you should check if your dependency is downloaded. Check maven directory (default for linux ~/.m2) subdirectory commons-net/commons-net/3.3. Are you see any jar file? If no you should synchronize your pom.xml as  prayagupd mentioned.

Comment: The error is on the scala REPL. When I try `mvn clean compile` I get `dependencies.dependency.version' for org.apache.commons.net:commons-net:jar is missing`. Do I have to download the jar file as well? I assumed maven would do that for me if I included the dependency. Edit: I will try synchronizing my pom.xml.

Comment: @DanMandel I though you are putting `<version>3.3</version>` as version. you 3.6 which is the latest version - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-net/commons-net/3.6

Comment: @prayagupd I just changed it to 3.6, but unfortunately I am still getting the same error. I can see the correct .jar file inside my /.m2/ folder so I do not understand what I'm missing. Is it wrong that I am trying to run scalac on the file? I cannot even compile it.

Comment: scalac would need classpath to be included for ftp jar to work(like `scalac -cp /Users/as18/.ivy2/cache/commons-net/commons-net/jars/commons-net-3.6.jar`). Also did your `mvn clean compile` work? If yes its working fine and fix the IDE synchronisation.